# If a Galois connection does exists, how is it called?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders, galois-connections

Let $\phi$ be a function from a poset $B$ to a poset $A$.

$f \mapsto \min \{ g\in B \mid \phi(g) \geq f \}$ is called the *lower adjoint* of $\phi$ and $\phi$ is called an *upper adjoint*. These two functions together are called a *Galois connection*.

Is there any term for $f \mapsto \inf \{ g\in B \mid \phi(g) \geq f \}$ (specifically in the case if the lower adjoint does not exist and in the case if $B$ is a complete lattice)?

I've asked only about terminology, not about properties. However may properties be also interesting.